# Why bean id requires with same name into my example? and why bean file never returns my output as i change it values into bean configuration file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, output

I'm completely a beginner in `Spring framework`. I'm playing with an example of creating an instance of an object at the time. So will need your help!

Have a look into this example:

`MainApp.java`:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
        HelloWorld obj1=(HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloBd2");

        obj1.setMessage("fooo..");
        obj1.getMessage();

        HelloWorld obj2=(HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloBd2");
        obj2.getMessage();
    }
}
```

**First Question:** *Why here `bean id` requires with the same name? otherwise it gives some errors as below..*

```
    Oct 18, 2014 1:28:44 PM 
    org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh INFO: Refreshing 
    org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1c12fb0: startup   
    date [Sat Oct 18 13:28:44 PDT 2014]; root of context hierarchy Oct 18, 2014 1:28:44 PM 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions   
    INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [beans.xml] Exception in  
    thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean 
    named 'helloBd1' is defined     at   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:641)    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1157)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:280)    at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)     at 
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)     at MainApp.main(MainApp.java:8)
```

Okay have a look into my `beans.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="helloBd2" class="HelloWorld" scope="singleton">
        <property name="message" value="foo with blah blah.."/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**Second question:** *Why this program returns as an output as..*

```
Message: fooo..
Message: fooo..
```

It must suppose to return my output as:

```
Message: fooo..
Message: foo with blah blah..
```

Because when i do change my values into `beans.xml` so it must goes all as well with beans configuration files, **Unfortunately nothing such happens! Why?**

Please help!

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you get

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'helloBd1' is defined at
```

There's nothing in your question referring to a `helloBd1` bean.

As for the output, you've declared your bean as

```
<bean id="helloBd2" class="HelloWorld" scope="singleton">
```

That is, it has **singleton** scope. This means that both

```
HelloWorld obj1=(HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloBd2");
HelloWorld obj2=(HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloBd2");
```

are the retrieving the same object on which you had originally called

```
obj1.setMessage("fooo..");
```

presumably changing the message to `fooo..`.

Comment: Yes, Clearly i get your point that i require to change its `scope` to **prototype** if i need to get that value from configuration file.. :) .. Is it?

Comment: @rajalala If you don't call `setMessage`, then the value will be the one from the configuration file.

Comment: Thanks man.. Okay one more thing If i use the same name `id` of **bean**. Why it gives an error .. ? As you told me but sorry i changed it into `helloBd1` but similar problem occurs with `helloBd2` too. Can you tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: @rajalala It's not clear to me what error you are referring to and which bean name/id you are using. You haven't declared a bean with name `helloBd1` so if you request one, it will fail. Can you edit your question with your new attempt and the error that occurred?

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake .. actually i never see back into my question that i cannot afford to use that **id name** into `bean configuration files` .. :p lol